# Would a power series that doesn't start with an exponent of 0 be useful?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

I was wondering if there was a special reason why power series are defined starting from x^0 as I am studying generating functions.

Comment: See [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series).  These are useful in complex analysis.  But, for simple "clothesline" generating function manipulations, you can usually just hang your terms starting at $x^0$.  Letting $x$ take on values is where you may require Laurent series.

Comment: https://www.austinrochford.com/posts/2013-11-01-generating-functions-and-fibonacci-numbers.html

Comment: Nothing wrong with starting from $x^k$, $k > 0$.  If you want $k < 0$ the sum will be undefined at $x=0$ so it's a rather special case (Laurent series)

Comment: Dzoooks, why hang the terms starting from x^0? I'm guessing we can start from anywhere but this is just based on convention?

Comment: Any series starting with an $x^k$ term can be written as starting from $x^0$ by having zero coefficients: $0x^0 + 0x^1 + \cdots + ax^k + \cdots$

Comment: If you started at $x$ say, when you multiply two generating functions, a common operation, you'd get a series that starts at $x^2$, which is rather inconvenient.  Of course, you can deal with it, but why bother?

Comment: The power series relates functions to polynomials.  Polynomials are nice to work with because we understand them pretty well.  Your general polynomial has an $x^0$ (aka constant) term.  But there is no reason why this constant term may not equal $0.$